# how to format javascript date dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: javascript

I have a date fomatted as dd/mm/yyyy format, how can I format as mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: Have a look at http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 4):

```js
var date = '23/03/2015';
var dateSplit = date.split('/');
var newDate = dateSplit[1]+'/'+dateSplit[0]+'/'+dateSplit[2];
```

This is the simplest solution which I have in mind, but it's not the best one, because it works only for the format which you gave. For more general solution I'd [parse the date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) to `Date()` object and then use the [methods](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp) to extract the required information

Answer (score 4):

As I understand, you have a string format date?

Just use simple regex replace.

```
var toFormat = 'dd/mm/yyyy';
var formated = toFormat.replace(/(..)\/(..)\/(....)/, "$2/$1/$3");
// formated is now 'mm/dd/yyyy'
```

However this is a hackish way to do stuff. You might want to use a library such as moment.js if you require more datetime manipulation

Answer (score 3):

As **an universal solution**, you can combine the 3 main functions of `Date` to get desired string. It will work for any kind of date format input.

```
getDate() // To get date
getMonth() // To get month
getFullYear() // To get year
```

You may want to do following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var date = new Date();
    var curr_date = date.getDate();
    var curr_month = date.getMonth() + 1; // months are zero based
    var curr_year = date.getFullYear();
    document.write(curr_month + "/" + curr_date + "/" + curr_year);
</script>
```

Get [more insight](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/10_ways_to_format_time_and_date_using_javascript.php3) of it.

Answer (score 2):

I would use http://momentjs.com/

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // April 15th 2015, 3:03:45 pm
moment().format('dddd');                    // Wednesday
moment().format("MMM Do YY");               // Apr 15th 15
moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');     // 2015 escaped 2015
moment().format();                          // 2015-04-15T15:03:45+03:00
```